# Visual Illustration of a Geometric Theorem

Tags: geometry, limits, graph-theory, circles

I am reading about the following theorem called the "Honeycomb Conjecture" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9906042.pdf):

[image]

This is a very famous theorem that proved that out of all possible tiling arrangements, "a hexagonal tiling has the smallest possible perimeter to the area ratio". This ratio is roughly 1.86.

I am trying to understand how this above theorem describes the problem of the Honeycomb Conjecture. Here is what I have understood so far:

- A locally connected graph is a graph in which any node can only have a finite number of edges.
- A hexagonal grid (tiling) can be interpreted as a "locally finite graph" - each vertex of a hexagon can be a node, and each length of a hexagon can be an edge.
- "B" is a disk with radius "r".
- "C" represents a "plane" (in R-2) that contains an infinite number of disks "B"

But beyond this, I am really struggling to understand the above theorem. For instance, below I have drawn an empty plane "C" and the same plane "C" containing hexagonal tilings (in R-2):

[image]

Next, I have shown the plane "C" containing an "infinite" number of bounded discs "B" with radius "r" (as well as the plane "C" containing infinite bounded discs "B" with radius "r" containing hexagonal tilings):

[image]

But I am having trouble connecting everything together.

**How could we draw some pictures that illustrate this theorem? Can someone please help me show how "C", "B" and "r" would look like in some drawing/visual diagram? How would we illustrate the unions and intersections of these components? Would it be possible to show how this drawing/visual diagram changes as "r" becomes bigger and bigger? Could we also show (12^0.25) in this drawing/visual diagram?**

Thank you!

Comment: There is only one disc B centered at the origin. This is used as a way of getting rid of infinities. There is an infinite tiling with tiles of area 1, and C is the interior of the tiles. You can't directly compare the perimeter of C and the area of C since both are infinite. Therefore you look at a finite patch of the tiling, the part that lies inside a disc B, and then let that disc get larger. By taking the limit you look at the infinite tiling without ever using infinity itself.